# order by in inner join while updating table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I need to update a table by inner joining another table. Below is the example.

```
Employee table:

role        name    Time create
manager     abc      2013
sales       def      2014
manager     xyz      2015
sales       dje      2015

Currentteam:

role      name
manager 
sales
```

I need to update `Currentteam` table with name from employee table, but I need to update recent name meaning for the `manager` role. We have two names in the `Employee` table, but I need to update only one name which is recent — that is, `XYZ`. I tried to do something like the below, but it is not allowing `order by` in the sub query.

```
Update currentteam
Set name=temp.name
From currentteam
Inner join (select * from employee order by timecreate) as temp on temp.role=currentteam
```

Please advise!!!

Comment: Please choose the database you are using and tag appropriates.  MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: "Please advise!!!" ---
Why not be polite and ask nicely?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being nice but i didn't mean it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2383/1/0)

```
UPDATE  ct
    SET ct.name = (
        SELECT TOP 1 name
        FROM Employee e
        WHERE e.role = ct.role
        ORDER BY TimeCreate DESC
    )
FROM CurrentTeam ct
```

RESULT:

```
|    role | name |
|---------|------|
| manager |  xyz |
|   sales |  dje |
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, `row_number()` to the rescue:

```
Update currentteam
    Set name = temp.name
From currentteam Inner join
     (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by role order by timecreate desc) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) temp
     on temp.role = currentteam and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: this is also working but query provided by wewesthemenace is less complex so i marked that as an answer..thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Vicky . . . That answer does seem simpler.